# R read file which contains column with 001000 values

Tags: file, r, dataframe

I'd like to read a file which contain 2 columns.

```
2 00001
9 00001
3 00001
12 00001
115 00001
11 00001
12 00001
38 00001
```

if I use the standard `read.table`, I end up with something like that :

```
   V1 V2
1   2  1
2   9  1
3   3  1
4  12  1
5 115  1
6  11  1
```

Do you have any idea on how I could read this file, and keep the 2nd column as it is?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was confused with the documentation, this is why I asked ;)
Managed to find it:

```
 read.table("file.txt", colClasses=c("character"))
```

Comment: And if you wanted the first col to be numeric then:  read.table("file.txt", colClasses=c("numeric", "character") )

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation for `read.table()` and learn about how select column types. You want the second column as character.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can pass an argument `as.is` to change whether read.table attempts to parse strings into values, or keep them as raw strings.

> as.is     the default behavior of read.table is to convert character variables (which are not converted to logical, numeric or complex) to factors. The variable as.is controls this conversion. Its value is either a vector of logicals (values are recycled if necessary), or a vector of numeric or character indices which specify which columns should not be converted to factors.
>
> Note: to suppress all conversions including those of numeric columns, set colClasses = "character".

http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/r-project/arch/i386_rhel3/lib/R/library/base/html/read.table.html

Answer (score 2):

In general I´d go with Dirk's answer. But maybe a little note helps someone who stumbles across this thread looking how to handle not-so-common data formats. 
Have also a look at `read.fwf` from the `utils` package. That is really nice if you have data stored without separators like in some old databases.

That being said, in your particular case I´d go with read.table probably.